# How to send an Email to User depending on the value of the wordpress-method get_post_meta()?

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer

I implemented a function in my Wordpress admin panel, which is a checkbox. I like to send a email to that specific user, when I check the box or uncheck the box on his specific post and hit the save-button on the upper right corner.

When I check the box, a warning field appears on users post. When I uncheck it, the warning disappears. For now I worked with the `get_post_meta()` method.

**I like to send a email to the user as a warning automatically, if I manually check the warning-box**.

I have tried this but it did not work...

```
$warning = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'warningbox', true );

if ($warning == 1) {
    sendMailToUser();
}
```

I guess this is not the right solution, so how can I implement this function?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `sendMailToUser()` is defined, that's not a standard WordPress function. Either way, a custom function isn't really necessary there.

You'll want to hook into the [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) hook, check the value of the `post_meta` field, and then use the [`wp_mail()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) function to alert the post author. It almost sounds like using an AJAX function would be handier here, but that's also more complicated.

Something like this should be more than sufficient:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'alert_author_warningbox', 99, 2 );
function alert_author_warningbox( $post_ID, $post ){
    if( get_post_meta($post_ID, 'warningbox', true) == 1 ){
        $to      = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $post_ID );
        $subject = sprintf( 'Warning Box enabled for "%s"', $post->post_title );
        $message = 'The warning box for your post has been enabled. Please contact the admin to resolve this warning.';

        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok Thank you very much that is great. But a little mistake is, does not matter if I check or uncheck the box in admin panel, it sends the email in both cases. But I like to have it send email ONLY on check the warning box. The values for that are 1 or 0. How do I do this?

Comment: filter validating the boolean should work. If not, for some reason, I've updated the code (as well as lowered the priority down to 99).

Comment: It did not work. Emails are send if check or UNcheck. When it is saved unchecked it should send no emails...

Comment: It sounds like you may be having an issue with your actual updating/saving of the meta field. The `save_post` hook runs after the post has been saved, and both iterations check for a `1` or a truthy value in that if-statement. I'd make sure your `warningbox` field is named and being saved appropriately